# Need step by step instructions on creating a Postgres-bound Monomac application

Tags: postgresql, mono, monomac

I've been struggling through this by looking at the sparse documentation and it's a pretty hard slog to say the least.  Has anyone done a simple tutorial that would walk one through creating an OSX application with Mono (presumably Monomac) that binds to a Postgres database?

Answer (score 1):

To use PostgreSQL with Mono you simply need to use [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/).